# How to make an ongoing game?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm working on a java Memory game using 2d arrays. There is a 4x4 grid of numbers. Each turn the player picks two numbers and those two array cells are turned over to reveal back. If the colors don't match the cards turn over and the player must go again. So far I've created mechanics of the game. The array is there, the player can turn over the cells, but the code stops after the first try. I need to change it so the program keeps running until the player has successfully matched all cards. Furthermore, if the player matches two cards, those cards must not turn back around. I have two classes: Card and MemoryGame. Here they are:

```
public class Card{
    boolean showing; // true or false, indicates that the card is flipped
    String back;     //hidden symbol on the back of the card
    int front;       //integer on the front of the card

    public Card(String theBack, int theFront)
    {
        showing = false; 
        back = theBack;
        front = theFront;
    }

    //
    public void showCard()
    {
        if(showing)
            System.out.print(String.format(back)); //if showing is true, it shows the hidden symbol
        else
            System.out.print(String.format("["+front+"]"));
    }

    public void setShowingStatus()
    {
        if(showing)
            showing = false;
        else
            showing = true;
    }
}
```

And this is the memory game class. The playGame() method and choosePairofCards() methods are the one I need help completing.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MemoryGame{
    //Declaration
    private Card[][] board;
    private String[] words = {"Blue", "Blue","Red","Red","Green","Green","Yellow","Yellow","Pink","Pink","Black","Black","Brown", "Brown","White","White"};
    private Random r; 
    private Scanner reader; 

    MemoryGame(){
        r = new Random();
        reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        board = new Card[4][4]; //Creates the 4x4 array that can hold Card objects
        shuffle();
        setCells();
        printCells();
        playGame();
    }

    public void shuffle(){
        // Has a loop that goes throught the array of words and chooses a random position and swaps the words
        // For loop position to random position
        // Words array is shuffled
        for(int a=0; a<words.length; a++){
            int pos = r.nextInt(words.length);
            String temp = words[a];
            words[a] = words[pos];
            words[pos] = temp;
        }
    }

    public void setCells(){
        //Designates the words
        int a = 0; 
        for (int row = 0; row<board.length; row++){
            for (int col = 0; col<board[0].length; col++){
                {
                    board[row][col] = new Card(words[a], a); //Creates new Card that pulls words from Shuffled array
                    a++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void printCells(){
        Card aCard; //Local variable = aCard, which is a type Card
        for (int row = 0; row<board.length; row++){
            for(int col = 0; col<board[0].length; col++){
                aCard = board[row][col];
                aCard.showCard();
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public void playGame(){
        //INCOMPLETE
        choosePairOfCards();
    }

    public void choosePairOfCards(){

        int cardChoice, row1, col1, row2, col2;
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Enter the number on the card.");
        System.out.println("First Card Choice? >");
        cardChoice = getInputAsInt();
        row1 = cardChoice / 4;
        col1 = cardChoice % 4;
        board[row1][col1].setShowingStatus();

        System.out.print("Second Card Choice? >");
        cardChoice = getInputAsInt();
        row2 = cardChoice / 4;
        col2 = cardChoice % 4;
        board[row2][col2].setShowingStatus();

        System.out.print('\u000C'); //clears the screen

        printCells(); // INCOMPLETE
        // check to see if the "cards" match
        //if they don't then turn print game with cards turned around
    }

    public int getInputAsInt(){
        String temp = reader.nextLine();
        return Integer.parseInt(temp); //Returns a String containing integer, into an int value
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe the 'INCOMPLETE' `playGame()` needs to be completed? Right now it calls a turn only once. Maybe look into [while-loops](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html)?

Comment: @n247s I wrote incomplete to indicate what needs to be worked on. The while loop is what I need help on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To implement an infinite running game you can simply use a while loop. In that while loop you simply keep turning. If the game is over, stop the loop and let the program finnish. For example imagine you got a methid `isGameFinnished` which returns true if the gamd is finnished, and false othewise.

```
while(true)
{
    choosePairOfCards();
    if(isGameFinnished())
        break;
}
```

The above example breaks activly out of the loop. When you can simply check a boolean value like abovr, you can of course also do

```
while(!isGameFinnished())
{
    choosePairOfCards();
}
```

I hope this helped you in the right direction.